# Adding things in an array together, with values set by type-in box?

Tags: php

How do I get to add the things in the boxes using arrays? I have the code below.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Type in the amount of money earned from each business and press the button.</p>

    Department 1:<input type="text" name="dep1" />
    <br/>
    Department 2:<input type="text" name="dep2" />
    <br/>
    Department 3:<input type="text" name="dep3" />
    <br/>
    Department 4:<input type="text" name="dep4" />
    <br/>
    Department 5:<input type="text" name="dep5" />
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit!" />

</form>

<?
error_reporting(false);

$dep1 = $_POST['dep1'];
$dep2 = $_POST['dep2'];
$dep3 = $_POST['dep3'];
$dep4 = $_POST['dep4'];
$dep5 = $_POST['dep5'];

$deparray = array(1=>"Department 1", 2=>"Department 2", 3=>"Department 3", 4=>"Department 4", 5=>"Department 5");

foreach($deparray as $key=>$value)
{
    echo 
}
```

The echo at the end is where I'm lost at. It's tallying the total cost of the department earnings typed in the boxes. I think you can do this easier using arrays instead of using functions...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Type in the amount of money earned from each business and press the button.</p>

    Department 1:<input type="text" name="dep[1]" />
    <br/>
    Department 2:<input type="text" name="dep[2]" />
    <br/>
    Department 3:<input type="text" name="dep[3]" />
    <br/>
    Department 4:<input type="text" name="dep[4]" />
    <br/>
    Department 5:<input type="text" name="dep[5]" />
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit!" />

</form>

<?
if( isset($_POST['go']) ){
    $deparray = array(1=>"Department 1", 2=>"Department 2", 3=>"Department 3", 4=>"Department 4", 5=>"Department 5");

    $sum = 0.0;
    foreach($deparray as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo "Sales for ".$value.": ".$_POST['dep'][$key]."<br>"; // prints the sales for each dept.
        $sum += floatval($_POST['dep'][$key]);
    }
    echo "Sum for all departments: "+$sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want when the form is submitted you have the form with the submitted values in the textbox with the calculations/sum of the values.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['go'])){
        $dep1 = floatval($_POST['dep1']);
        $dep2 = floatval($_POST['dep2']);
        $dep3 = floatval($_POST['dep3']);
        $dep4 = floatval($_POST['dep4']);
        $dep5 = floatval($_POST['dep5']);

        $sum = $dep1 + $dep2 + $dep3 +$dep4 + $dep5;

    } 
 ?>
 <form action="<?=  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
     <p>Type in the amount of money earned from each business and press the button.</p>

     Department 1:<input type="text" name="dep1" value="<?php if(isset($dep1)) echo $dep1;?>" />
     <br/>
     Department 2:<input type="text" name="dep2"  value="<?php if(isset($dep2)) echo $dep2;?>"/>
     <br/>
     Department 3:<input type="text" name="dep3"  value="<?php if(isset($dep3)) echo $dep3;?>"/>
     <br/>
     Department 4:<input type="text" name="dep4"  value="<?php if(isset($dep4)) echo $dep4;?>" />
     <br/>
     Department 5:<input type="text" name="dep5"  value="<?php if(isset($dep5)) echo $dep5;?>"/>
     <br/>

     <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit!" />

</form>

<?php
   if(isset($sum))
     echo "<p>The total amount earned is: ".$sum."</p>";
?>
```

The submitted values will be present in the textboxes after the post and there will be an output string stating the total.

Hope this helps.